# como criar um vetor de vetores?

Tags: java, array

Alguém pode me dizer como criar um vetor de vetores em java? ou seja Como fazer um vetor armazenar outros vetores com valores int

esse laço popula um vetor com valores de 1 a 4 q são direções N=Norte, S=Sul, L=Leste, O=Oeste.

```
for (int i =0; i < aux; i ++) {

        v[i] = (int) (Math.random() *4);

        if(v[i] == 0){
             N++;
        System.out.println("N");}
        if(v[i] == 1){
            S++;
        System.out.println("S");}
        if(v[i] == 2){
            L++;
        System.out.println("L");}
        if(v[i] == 3){
            O++;
        System.out.println("O");} 
    }
```

meu objetivo é armazenar os resultados em outros 4 vetores

Comment: Bem-vinda ao SO, Joyce!
O conceito que você procura seria o de matrizes, talvez? v[i][j]

Comment: Array de array de quantas dimensoes? 2? é Só adicionar mais um par de `[]` na frente q voce adiciona mais uma dimensao.

Comment: o array é de tamanho variado pois uso um rand pra atribuir um valor qualquer( entre 0 e 10) à variavel aux. Então no fim ficam 4 arrays com tamanhos variados e com varios numeros aleatórios dentro. Talvez matriz seja a solução queria q ficasse assim 

array1 = N O L S O L L N O L

array2 = N N N L O S L O L O L

....etc

sendo q cada letra representa um numero q será contado

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar `HashMap`. Veja código abaixo:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SingleObject {

    private static SingleObject instance;

    private static Map<String,Integer> pontos = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    private SingleObject() {
        pontos.put( "N", 0);
        pontos.put( "S", 0);
        pontos.put( "L", 0);
        pontos.put( "O", 0);
    }

    public static SingleObject getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new SingleObject();
        return instance;
    }

    public void increment(String opcao) {
        Integer opc = pontos.get(opcao);
        pontos.replace(opcao, opc + 1);
    }

    public void exibir() {
        System.out.println(pontos);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleObject o = SingleObject.getInstance();
        o.increment("L");
        o.increment("N");
        o.increment("N");
        o.increment("N");
        o.increment("O");
        o.exibir();

        o.increment("L");
        o.increment("O");
        o.increment("N");
        o.increment("S");
        o.increment("S");
        o.increment("O");
        o.exibir();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu realmente quero que retorne um arraylist preenchido com vetores aleatórios do principal, não importa se for repetido ou não. Ex: Vamor supor que o seja sorteado o vetor de número 6. Nele contém 1, 5, 3, 8, 6. Eu quero que esses valores sejam preenchidos na primeira posição do arraylist temp. Depois sorteia outro vetor e assim por diante. Repare que não importa se cair novamente o vetor número 6, se ele cair, terei que preencher em temp assim mesmo em outro índice. então teria msm q ser um vetor q guardaria outro vetor

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma lista de vetores, usando a interface List ([leia mais sobre a interface e seus métodos clicando aqui](https://www.journaldev.com/11444/java-list)), implementando a classe ArrayList. Seguindo seu exemplo, ficaria algo assim:

```
List<int[]> listaDeVetores = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int i =0; i < aux; i ++) {
    v[i] = (int) (Math.random() *4);

    if(v[i] == 0){
        N++;
        System.out.println("N");}
    if(v[i] == 1){
        S++;
        System.out.println("S");}
    if(v[i] == 2){
        L++;
        System.out.println("L");}
    if(v[i] == 3){
        O++;
        System.out.println("O");}
    //adiciona o vetor da vez na lista.
    listaDeVetores.add(v);
}
```

Mas analisando o problema que vc propos, sempre são 4 "direções" que existem, logo, criaria uma classe com os atributos N,S,L e O, e faria uma lista apenas dessa classe e não uma lista de vetores, ficando, dessa forma, mais fácil a manutenção e manuseio dos atributos.

Comment: falei pro colega acima quero que retorne um arraylist preenchido com vetores aleatórios do principal, não importa se for repetido ou não. Ex: Vamor supor que o seja sorteado o vetor de número 6. Nele contém 1, 5, 3, 8, 6. Eu quero que esses valores sejam preenchidos na primeira posição do arraylist temp. Depois sorteia outro vetor e assim por diante. Repare que não importa se cair novamente o vetor número 6, se ele cair, terei que preencher em temp assim mesmo em outro índice. então teria msm q ser um vetor q guardaria outro vetor